# Why delegate doesn't works in main.js while it does works in index.html?

Tags: javascript, ajax, delegates

In my codes the delegate function doesn't works when i use it inside main.js while when the script used in html it does works.

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("body").delegate(".menu_s", "click",function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var menu_id=$(this).attr('menu_id');
            alert(menu_id)
        });
    });
</script>
```

The code for main.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("body").delegate(".menu_s", "click",function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var menu_id=$(this).attr('menu_id');
            alert(menu_id)
        });
```

Comment: `delegate` has been deprecated and removed from jQuery, that could be the reason.

Comment: Can you please add the code from the main.js aswell?

Comment: any error in browser console?

Comment: @adeneo it's been deprecated as of 3.0. but it hasn't been removed. http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ . However, since 1.7, using `.on` has been recommended instead, so I'm surprised OP is still trying to use such an out of date function.

Comment: There's no special reason it shouldn't work when within main.js, as long as it's still within a `document.ready()` block to allow it to bind after the page has fully loaded.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for your attention the  _.on_ does work!